# Parsing search queries for SQL 2008 FTS

Tags: sql-server, search, full-text-search

We want to use SQL SERVER 2008 Full Text Search and seem to run into a lot of problems handling the search query.

If the user types in "blue dog" it just crashes sql unless we parse the search terms to include the "" around the words but that makes it a phrase instead of keywords.

I want results where blue or dog are included but that means replacing spaces with or(s) and so on. Unfortunately there seem to be far too many combination a user might type.

Are there any libraries out there (for .net) that can already parse a search string into something FT understands?

We'd like a Google like syntax :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the "FREETEXT" option and was using the "CONTAINS" keyword instead, my bad. Freetext is giving me the results I wanted.